# Does a namespace for IDependencyContainer exist?

Tags: c#, uwp

I used [this](https://maximelabelle.wordpress.com/2017/01/19/implementing-viewmodel-based-navigation-in-your-universal-app/?unapproved=2021&moderation-hash=850d7ab1728a956e3c6d645fce00ec8c#comment-2021) tutorial to learn about navigation using dependency injection: "Implementing ViewModel-based Navigation in your Universal App" by Maxime Labelle.

The tutorial does not mention a namespace or nuget package for the interfaces `IDependencyContainer` or `IDependencyResolver`.  And no mention of it in MSDN links.

Are these interfaces part of microsoft namespaces, or has the tutorial just omitted to include the code for them?

Comment: The author says "Here, any IoC container or framework will do but, again, for the purpose of this post, let’s use a simple implementation like this one:" and I believe he just forgot to add the source code for the interface, which looks like an interface with three methods, `void RegisterType(Type type, Type mappedTo)`, `void RegisterInstance(Type type, object instance)` and `public object Resolve(Type type)`

Comment: Thanks @OguzOzgul, I did not think of the idea that I could just create those interfaces myself. Was stuck in my mind, that it is part of system or something.